# How to remove a binary file from fossil history

Tags: fossil

This situation happens a little often, your whole repository has 2MB and then someone thinks it would be great to have a backup of selenium.jar with 20MB in repository. So everyone now must download a repository with at lest 22MB, and version after version of the new binary file the repository grows its size.

Is possible to remove a binary file from fossil? I read that one of fossil philosophies is to never rewrite history, but I don't want to rewrite history I just want to remove the history content like a missing artifact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does [shunning content](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/shunning.wiki) covers what you need? It effectively prevents the files from being synced.

Comment: I want to remove one large binary file and its history files. I've tried setting shun on the lastest binary file. When I rebuild, it seems does not reduce the repository file size. And I don't know how to shun older binary file.

Comment: Same thing, shunned files are not removed for me on rebuild. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

you could convert the history to git. and then look up 
how to remove file from git and then rebuild the fossil repository from that.
the only problem is the tickets and wiki are gone